# Allocating an array using a constant variable that has storage

Tags: c++, c

```
const int i = 100;
int *j = &i;
int array[i] = {0};
```

Is this legal? I read somewhere that without the &i, i and 100 would be added to the symbol-table, but because of the &i, storage is forced for i, and 100 would be stored in i at compile time; therefore the compiler would not be able to read the value of i (from storage) to allocate the array - is this true?

Comment: Which language. C or C++?

Comment: @djechlin Not a useful comment. Just because it works (or not) doesn’t necessarily say anything about legality.

Comment: both actually, the behavior is slightly different.

Comment: Why would the compiler need to read the value from storage? It *knows* the value is 100. So it has no need to read it.

Comment: @paleywiener: The fact that the behavior is slightly different is precisely the reason you need to specify only one language.  You can make another post for the other language.  As you can see, there are two answers, both different, and both correct.  Which one should be accepted?

Comment: A dynamic `VLA` aren't illegal in `C99 std`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this legal? I read somewhere that without the &i, i and 100 would be added to the symbol-table, but because of the &i, storage is forced for i, and 100 would be stored in i at compile time; therefore the compiler would not be able to read the value of i (from storage) to allocate the array - is this true?

Here's the language from the C99 standard:

> **6.7.3 Type qualifiers**
> ...
> 3 The properties associated with qualified types are meaningful only for expressions that
> are lvalues.<sup>114)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>114) The implementation may place a `const` object that is not `volatile` in a read-only region of
> storage. Moreover, the implementation need not allocate storage for such an object if its address is
> never used.</sup>

So, sort of true, but not really relevant in this case.  The compiler doesn't *have* to create storage for `i` to use its value elsewhere; it may simply use an immediate operand with the value of `100` in place of `i`.  Either way, the line `int j = &i;` is unnecessary.

`i` is not an integer constant expression, meaning it's not a compile-time constant (in C; C++ is different in this regard); it's a run-time variable whose value may not be modified during its lifetime.

As of C99, you can specify array sizes using a run-time variable, even one declared `const`, so

```
const int i = 100;
int array[i];
```

will allocate `array` as a 100-element array of `int`.  However, you cannot use an initializer with a VLA, so `int array[i] = {0};` is *not* valid.

Again, C++ is different, and doesn't support VLAs at all.  But since `i` is declared `const`, C++ treats it as a compile-time constant, meaning your code *should* be legal C++ (it builds for me, anyway).

More from C99:

> **6.7.5.2 Array declarators**
> ...
> 4 If the size is not present, the array type is an incomplete type. If the size is `*` instead of
> being an expression, the array type is a variable length array type of unspecified size,
> which can only be used in declarations with function prototype scope;<sup>124)</sup> such arrays are
> nonetheless complete types. If the size is an integer constant expression and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length array type;
> otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type.
> ...
> **6.7.8 Initialization**
> ...
> 3 The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or an object type
> that is not a variable length array type.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>124) Thus, * can be used only in function declarations that are not definitions (see 6.7.5.3).</sup>

Comment: In C99, VLAs with file scope are not allowed: "Only an ordinary identifier [...] with both block scope or function
prototype scope and no linkage shall have a variably modified type." (6.7.5.2, §2).

Answer (score 6):

In C90 and C99, the definition `int array[i] = {0};` is not legal (regardless of what you do with `i`).

An array declared at file scope has to have an integer constant expression as length (6.5.4.2 or 6.7.5.2, §2, resp.)

If the definition has function/block scope it is still illegal because

- in C90, variable length arrays are not allowed (6.5.4.2)
- in C99, variable length arrays must not be initialized (6.7.8, §3)

Answer (score 4):

`int *j = &i;` should be `const int *j = &i;`. After that, your code is legal.

EDIT: in C++

Answer (score 4):

There's absolutely no reason why a variable couldn't have both a compile-time constant value *and* physical storage. Thus it depends on the standards of the language.

C++ allows a constant integer to be a compile-time constant. C does not. Some C++ compilers which also compile C will mix and match some features of both languages so your compiler might accept it as an extension to the standard.